# How to pass URL entered by user in form action on click of submit using Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<body>
    <form name="testarea" method="post" action="?URL">
        <input type="text" id="test1" name="URL"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Now I want to:

1. Use the value entered by the user in the text box for the URL
2. For passing to form `action=''` on click of `Submit`. This need that same URL when passed on Submit will launch the URL in the same iFrame.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to set the action attribute of your form as follows:

```
var url = $("#test1").val();
$(form).attr("action", url)
```

If you are unable to use jquery you can refer to the following post:

http://netfactory.dk/2007/09/28/changing-a-form-submit-url-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You can use method Get instead of Post

```
<body>
<form name ="testarea" Method="Get" Action="youpage.html">
<input type='text' id='test1' name='URL'/>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

UPDATE:

I didn't know this is correct but you can also try like this

```
<input type='text' id='test1' name=''/>
<input type='button' value='Submit' onclick="window.location.href=window.location+'?'+document.getElementById('test1').value;"/>
```

Comment: But I want to Pass Value of URL into Form Action.

Answer (score 0):

Place the following snippet **after** your form:

```
function addListener(element, eventName, handler) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
    }
    else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, handler);
    }
    else {
        element['on' + eventName] = handler;
    }
}

var form = document.forms['testarea'];
var input = document.getElementById('test1');

addListener(form, 'submit', function () {
   var url = input.value;
   form.setAttribute('action', url);
});
```

I haven't tested it but it should work. I recommend you use a library such as jquery instead of writing pure javascript. You'll make life easier and have less crossbrowser issues.

In jQuery your code would look like this:

```
​$('form[name="testarea"]').on('submit', function () {
    var url = $('#test1').val();
    $(this).attr('action', url);    
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```